# How can I tell how many python threads a process has from the outside?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, cpython

I have a large python program, that has a performance issue. The cause of the issue is as yet unidentified.

The application frequently has 32 threads running, according to csysdig.

CPython, in which the application is written, is bad at CPU-bound threads.  So I'm wondering if the performance problem is because Python threads are being used for something CPU-bound.

My question is, in csysdig or sysdig or similar tool (or code instrumentation), is there a way of distinguishing between Python threads and threads that come from a C/C++ extension module?

I've googled, but didn't find anything at all - just tutorials about how to use threads.

I've also searched the Python code for the string "thread", and only found a few occurrences that don't appear to account for the problem.

I'm identifying the threads running in the CPython application using:

```
csysdig -p"procname:%proc.name threadcount:%proc.nthreads" proc.name contains python
```

That's how I know it has a bunch of threads running.

I want to find out how many threads are CPython threads, and how many are from C/C++ extension modules, without studying the entire large codebase.

If I need to add some code to the Python application to find this information, that's fine.

Comment: maybe try `perf top -s dso`

Comment: This is the first time I've looked at perf top -s dso, but it seems like it's more about showing where in virtual memory shared objects are mapped than about threads and their origins.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I know this doesn't quite answer your question. But it allows you to distinguish if most CPU time is spent by CPython itself, versus non-Python extension modules and their libraries or even the kernel.